# Getting CORS error in my angular application when try to call local hosted node express api

Tags: angular, cors

I am facing CORS issue and its very difficult to find a solution. I have a Node api application which was build using express and the consumer is a simple angular application. I tried many solutions like using CORS, and including the headers but no use. I have attached my api and the angular api calling code below.

API file - which is "http://localhost:8082/login"

```js
const taskRoute = require('./routers/task.route');
const uploadRoute = require('./routers/upload.route');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT

app.use(express.json());
app.use(userRouter);
app.use(loginRoute);
app.use(taskRoute);
app.use(uploadRoute);

app.use(cors());
//below are the other examples that  have tried to resolve the issue
// app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
//     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');  
//     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
//     next();
// });
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at the port ' + port);
});
```

Angular App which is "http://localhost:4200"

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Environmentprovider } from './env.provider';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class APIService {    
    private appConfiguration;
    private today: Date;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private envProvider: Environmentprovider) {
        this.today = new Date();
    }

    initilizeHeader(){        
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':`application/json`,
            'Accept':`*/*`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `*`
        });
        return headers;
    };

    public post(relativeURI: string, body: any): Observable<any>{
        let header = {headers: this.initilizeHeader()};
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8082/login',body, header);
    }
}
```

but still I am getting the CORS error.[CORS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCnAv.png)

Please some one help me fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route, containing the endpoint you are hitting, is added to the `app` **before** the `cors()` middleware.

Order matters. The first code for a URL is run first, and the first which ends with a response (instead of a `next()`) ends the chain.

Consequently the middleware is never run.

Move `app.use(cors())` above all the routes you want it to apply to.